# Python - shutil How to select multiple directories for deletion with similar names

Tags: python, glob, xbmc, shutil, kodi

I have a Directory called "master" inside I have sub directories as so.

```
|master----
         |test.directory.one
         |test directory.two
         |test.directory.three
         |test.directory.four
         |test.directory.five
         |this.directory.keep
```

I would like to create a python script that deletes

all the directories that start with ***test.directory*** and ignore anything else

Thanks for you help. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Simontfs

Comment: Are you using glob patterns? Please post the code that you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import glob
import shutil

deldirs = glob.glob("path/to/master/test.directory.*")
for dir_ in deldirs:
    shutil.rmtree(dir_)
```

Comment: do you mean shutil.rmtree?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham hmm yes. I even looked it up because I couldn't remember if it was `shutil.rmtree` or `unlinktree` or `rmdir` or etc. Apparently I wasn't paying much attention!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Adam Smith,

It was almost what I was looking for here is the edited code.

```
import glob
import xbmc
import os
import shutil

TARGETFOLDER = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/addons/')

addonvideo = glob.glob(xbmc.translatePath('special://home/addons/plugin.video.*'))
for dirname in addonvideo:
    shutil.rmtree(dirname)
```

Im creating some maintenance scripts for Kodi, I'm new to python but slowly getting my head around it, with the help of you guys. Thanks a million!

I am going to elaborate on this code and would like to post back if I need some more guidance if poss. Cheers :)